# ffmpeg install fail OSX 10.7.2

Tags: ffmpeg, installation, osx-lion

Can you help me?

I try to install a ffmpeg using a brew, but i can't.

It seems like the dependencies was successfully installed.

I am using a Mac OSX 10.7.2 and the XCode 4.2.1.

I couldn't install ffmpeg.

I've tried:

```
brew install ffmpeg
brew install --use-clang ffmpeg
brew install --use-clang --HEAD ffmpeg
```

And they've all failed.

This is the result log.

```
$ brew install --use-clang ffmpeg
==> Downloading http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.9.1.tar.bz2
File already downloaded in /Users/brunogermano/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.9.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --cc=/usr/bi
ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
==> Exit Status: 1
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ffmpeg.rb#L61
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8.1
HEAD: 44213dfb4861c1307fdc4ae41e139404f0e1ffb1
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
Hardware: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.7.2
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 4.2.1
GCC-4.0: N/A
GCC-4.2: N/A
LLVM: build 2336
Clang: 3.0 build 211
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
"--use-clang" was specified
CC: /usr/bin/clang
CXX: /usr/bin/clang++ => /usr/bin/clang
LD: /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -march=native
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -march=native
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/X11/include
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/X11/lib
MAKEFLAGS: -j2

Error: Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.9.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8456
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8815
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9399
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
We saved the configure log, please gist it if you report the issue:
    ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/config.log
```

This is the brew doctor log:

```
$ brew doctor
Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.52.108.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavcore.0.16.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.52.2.3.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavfilter.1.74.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavformat.52.93.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavutil.50.36.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libfaad.2.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libguide.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libswscale.0.12.0.dylib

Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavcore.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavutil.a
    /usr/local/lib/libfaad.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmp4ff.a
    /usr/local/lib/libswscale.a

Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavcore.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavfilter.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavformat.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libswscale.pc

Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libfaad.la
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.la

We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler.
NOTE: Versions of XCode newer than 4.2 don't include gcc 4.2.x.

==> /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. This is an issue if you eg. brew installed Python.

Consider editing your .bashrc to put:
  /usr/local/bin
ahead of /usr/bin in your PATH.
Some brews install binaries to sbin instead of bin, but Homebrew's
sbin was not found in your path.

Consider editing your .bashrc to add:
  /usr/local/sbin
to the PATH variable.

Some "config" scripts were found in your path, but not in system or Homebrew folders.

`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if software packages
are installed, and what additional flags to use when compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via Homebrew if
the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided script of the same name.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
    python-config python2.5-config
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed without using the `brew`.

I installed manually the `x264` and then I installed `ffmpeg`.

I had a little help from this site:

http://hunterford.me/compiling-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Page is gone, still cached in google though.
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hunterford.me/compiling-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 8):

Actually was able to solve this error with:

```
 $brew uninstall lame
 $brew install lame
 $sudo brew link lame
```